# Python. One line for loop printer with format

Tags: python

What is the best way to achieve something like this

```
items = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print("Items:")
for i in items:
    print("\t", i)
```

in one line statement? This does not do what I want, because is adding tabulator only between items, not in front of every one:

```
print("\n\t".join(items))
```

I want output to look like this:

```
Items:
    a
    b
    c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
print("Items:\n\t" + "\n\t".join(['a', 'b', 'c']))
```

Or this i you prefer a for loop:

```
print "Items:"
for i in ['a', 'b', 'c']: print "\t" + i
```

Comment: Looks good, but I'm looking for cleaner solution. Something like print(d for d in items)

Comment: You wrote a clean solution yourself, but you wanted a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

you can use print function.

```
>>> items = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> print ('\t', *items, sep='\t')
        a   b   c
```

Comment: That's only if you have Python 3.

Comment: This is exactly what the OP DOES NOT want.

Answer (score 0):

You can always patch `items` so that `\n\t` would appear at the beginning as well:
So if

```
print("\n\t".join(items))
```

results in

```
a\n\tb\n\tc
```

This

```
print("\n\t".join([''] + items))
```

results in

```
\n\ta\n\tb\n\tc
```

or

```
items = ['', 'a', 'b', 'c']
print("\n\t".join(items))
```